# Is there a good email service to replace Salesforce's email service as a workaround for the attachment size limit?

Tags: email, limits, external-app

I like Salesforce's email service in that I can:

- Send emails to any contact in the database
- Use templates
- Track and log activities from emails

However, I can't send attachments larger than around 4mb and the total email size has similar size limits (25mb maybe?). This is a big deal since I'm trying to drive user adoption from gmail users who are used to a 25mb limit per attachment and no limit for the total email size.

What I'm looking for is some kind of email service that accepts

- Subject
- Body
- List of contacts to send to, cc, and bcc
- List of attachments (as a reference link preferably since apex has a
  limit size on data it can transfer) with a 25mb attachment size limit per attachment and a higher total email size limit

The email service would need to support SMTP since our actual mail needs to be sent by Gmail's servers.

Do you guys know of any service, preferably an app on top of Salesforce, that would comply with those requirements?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

In lightning there is now the option to send directly through Gmail / office365

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_email_integration.htm

This knowledge article has some more detail on email sending options.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Which-Email-Setup-is-Best-for-My-Org&type=1

In classic, for single sends, the old school Gmail to salesforce adds a Gmail button next to the email field that worked pretty well when I used it 5 years ago.  It automatically bccs the users email to Salesforce address so the email gets logged

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=google_gmail_activate.htm&type=0

Sending to multiple contacts in classic seems more challenging.  Apps like pardot might have something to offer, certainly worth looking on the app exchange to see if anyone has a pre built solution.

Overall moving to lightning seems like the best long term.

Comment: Hmmm this is good for manually sending emails. But what if I need to send email programmatically?